# Foreign keys does not return error at 0

Tags: mysql

I've created below table, which is suppose to be a relational table between my tweets and team tables. However i seem to have some issue, since when i try to provoke an error with 0 in the tweetId it seem to accept this value even though no tweet has the id value 0?

```
CREATE TABLE tweet_contain
(
tweetId int ,
teamId int ,
FOREIGN KEY (teamId) REFERENCES team(id),
FOREIGN KEY (tweetId) REFERENCES tweets(id),
PRIMARY KEY (tweetId, teamId)
)
```

Comment: What engine do you use in MySQL? MyISAM does not support foreign keys

Comment: That might be the reason. Thank you!